# Tool to calculate occupied space in directory tree within a certain time-frame

Tags: windows, file-management

Is there any tool which can do this? I am using Total Commander for calculating occupied space in a directory tree, but I would like to limit it to files not older than certain amount of days, which I don't know how to do in Total Commander. Is there any such tool? For MS Windows.

Comment: What OS?  Please edit and tag accordingly.  Bash script in Linux would probably do this.  Powershell in Windows can definitely do it.  Powershell in Linux as well. (gasp, blasphemy)

Comment: @Xalorous I have specified the system already, as you can see in the tag. I want the question to be general accross all Windows versions.

Answer (score 1):

[Foldersize](http://www.foldersizes.com/) and [TreeSize](https://www.jam-software.com/treesize/).

Both come with dynamic filters to search by creation date/modification date etc. Foldersize also comes with charts and graphs for easier visualization.

Both are paid options.

Else, here is a power shell option command that lists files between two set dates.

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -ge "2016-09-01" -and $_.LastWriteTime -le "2016-09-30" -and !$_.PSIsContainer }
```

The above command checks for modified files between the month of September 2016.

- `Get-ChildItem` List files/folders in a given folder.
- `-Recurse` Recursively list all files.
- `Where-Object` Filters output based on given conditions.
- `LastWriteTime` Checks for the modified files between a set time. Use `CreationTime` if  you are looking to check file creation date.
- `!$_.PSIsContainer` Returns only files. `!` inverts the boolean where `PSIsContainer` is set to true for folders.

Answer (score 0):

As Xalorous pointed out it depends on your OS. For Windows a PowerShell script could be helpful. Based on [this Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17829785/delete-files-older-than-15-days-using-powershell) one possible solution could be:

```
# Set the path
$path = "<Directory>"

# Get a date which was 14 days ago, this will be how old files can be
$limit = (Get-Date).AddDays(-14)

# List all files and folders, including hidden ones, and select those which are not folders and whose creation time is "bigger" than limit
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse -Force -File | ?{$_.CreationTime -ge $limit }

$totalsize = 0
# build the sum of each files size
$files | %{$totalsize += $_.length}

echo ("Total size of all "+$files.length+" files is: "+$totalsize+" Bytes");
```

Possible other attributes in place of `CreationTime` could be (e.g.) `LastAccessTime` and `LastWriteTime`.

Comment: I have defined the system already, as you can see in the tags..

Comment: Yes you stated it was Windows but no which version. It could be 9x, 7, 10, NT 4.0, 2012 or any other version that was available. This does have an impact of whats available in PowerShell or if PowerShell is available at all. The above answer should work on most PowerShell versions. Other tools might be available for different versions.

Comment: I intentionally wanted to keep the question general for all versions of Windows. Usualy tools like Total Commander etc. are available for all windows versions.

Comment: No. There are a lot of tools that don't support Windows 9x anymore and certainly they don't support 16-Bit versions of Windows (e.g. 3.1 and earlier).

Comment: Use -File in your Get-ChildItem statement to pre-filter out the directories.  Then you only need to filter by date.  It will increase performance, and decrease system load.

Comment: @Tomas PowerShell is your answer from Windows 10 back to XP.  Before that, you'll need to dig through your list of tools and find older versions of tools and determine if they can do the trick.

Comment: @Xalorous thanks for that hint. Useful, kind of missed it while writing the script. Changed the post in accordance with it. :)

Comment: @Seth I think it was originally done the way you showed, and that way does work, but I try to always apply filters as early as I can as a practice, to minimize system impact.

Answer (score -2):

I tried to find the tool and I came accross a nice list of nice tools http://www.howtogeek.com/113012/10-best-free-tools-to-analyze-hard-drive-space-on-your-windows-pc/, as well as [this one](https://www.jam-software.com/treesize_free/) and [this one](http://www.mindgems.com/products/Folder-Size/Folder-Size.html). I tried [SpaceSniffer](http://www.uderzo.it/main_products/space_sniffer/index.html) since this one allows to filter the files according to date. It works great.

Comment: The downvotes are not the means to channel someones personal issues ;-) This is clearly an answer to the question so any downvote should be well explained.

Comment: I'll give you a downvote, AND an explanation.  You've just published an improper answer.  Asking for product recommendations is out of scope for superuser, and most (if not all) other stacks on stack exchange.  Come to think of it, the question gets a flag for removal as well.

Comment: Take heart, not only did they give you the answer, two people even went well above and beyond and wrote you scripts to do the work for you.

Comment: At least go ahead and list the programs that meet your criteria instead of just providng some links. What's the merit of SpaceSniffer which you picked? Ease of use? What kind of filters does it support etc.?